# Estimating dependent variable as sum of functions of independent variables

Tags: machine-learning, classification, linear-regression, svm

I have a training data of 5 columns, where c1 is the dependent variable and columns c2, c3, c4, c5 are independent variables.

I want to estimate c1 as sum of functions of ci (where i = 2, 3, 4, 5) in a way which minimizes residual error.

```
c1 ~ ( a2 F2(c2) + a3 F3(c3) + a4 F4(c4) + a5 F5(c5) )
```

I wrote a Python script to read columns c2, c3, c4, c5 for training. Now if I input a new row with c2, c3, c4, c5, then my script can generate c1 for this row.

But actually, what am I supposed to do by this statement "estimate c1 as sum of functions of ci (where i = 2, 3, 4, 5) in a way which minimizes residual error" ? I have no idea of ML, and would appreciate if somebody throws light on what is meant by estimating c1.

Thank you.

Comment: I think if the problem statement is not clear, your best bet is to clarify it with your instructor rather than ask strangers on the Internet to guess.

Comment: This is a statement from the LLD on which I need to work upon, and the team responsible for the LLD is not available due to management decisions. So thought to ask here.